# Ubuntu starts up in terminal after updating to newer version

Tags: boot, command-line, 15.10

I have searched the internet for hours, and although I have found some similar problems and extracted some information from them, I still have the same problem.

A few days ago I decided to update ubuntu from my 14.04 (I believe) version to the newer 15.10 version. 
The update procedure seemed to go jerky, my laptop eventually froze and I had to restart. When my laptop restarted it started Ubuntu in terminal mode. I could login with my user account but could not reach the desktop. I figured out that I can reach some version of the desktop by typing `startx`. But this version only contains the desktop icons. I cannot see my menu bar, cannot get internet connection and cannot connect usb sticks on this desktop version. 
I know that the update itself did succeed since I see that I know have Ubuntu 15.10 when I start my laptop.

Is there somebody who might be able to help me here? I have all my important stuff as backup so completely reinstalling Ubuntu is theoretically an option, but since I somehow cannot get the basic Ubuntu menu from usb stick (try Ubuntu etc), this is not as easy as it seems. I just want to use my laptop again.

Comment: It happened to me too. Im posting this as a comment because I dont know if it will work for you. Try using these commands in the terminal and then  reboot: `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: I have tried this but I get the report that the packages can't be retrieved. Probably due to the fact that I can't get internet connection (which is also a symptom that started after I tried updating to the new version since it worked fine before).

Comment: oh ok. Why don't you just download the newer version of ubuntu and make a bootable USB then click reinstall or choose the option that will allow you to keep all your files

Comment: This is what I ended up doing eventually. As I mentioned in my question, the new broken version did not read usb devices but fortunately it could be read in the bios menu. I could not keep my files here since trying this would make my laptop freeze every time I tried. Fortunately I had a back up of my most important stuff.

Thank you for the input in making my laptop work again!